# Is it safe to serialize a class instance with a resource reference attribute?

Tags: java, android, serialization, android-drawable, android-resources

I would like to **serialize** an object like:

```
   class Dog implements Serializable{

       public String name;
       public int iconDrawable;
    }
```

the `iconDrawable` is an int pointing to a **drawable resource** from R.java.

So i can just make a Dog like this:

```
Dog dog = new Dog();
dog.name= "Barky";
dog.iconDrawable = R.drawable.dog_icon; //portrait of a dog instance
```

My question is:

Is it **safe to serialize this object?** Is the iconDrawable is a final number and **do I get the same drawable always when i de-serialize?** Or the reference could change on app startup or app termination?

Or should I store the name of the drawable in a String attribute field and use `getIdentifier`? (Little more complicated but works for sure)

Comment: `do I get the same drawable always when i de-serialize?` with the same apk's compilation - yes ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

R.java is generated for you at build time. It will change if you modify (add, remove, etc) resources or possibly if a new version of the Android Build Tools is used to build the project.

That being said it would be safe to serialize/deserialize the resource id if you were only using it to transport the object to another activity/fragment or something similar during runtime.

However, if you are serializing it for persistence that would not be safe as those ids can change as mentioned between application builds. In that case it would be best to use `getIdentifier`.